# How BitTorrent client is able to connect to a IP address when my browser cant?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, browser, bittorrent, utorrent

My institute's router blocks all my http request on browser. The image below shows what I get when i type in google.com (while connected to my institute's router)
[image: browser when connected to router]

But I observed a weird thing. my bittorent client (utorrent app) is able to connect to peers and download torrents when I am connected to that same router. I was able to download over 4gb of torrents.
[image: uTorrent client when connected to router]v

This is the peerlist I got from my recent torrent download(successfully finished using that institute's router)

```
43.231.56.248:20473
196.235.182.163:24814
58-97-16-42.static.asianet.co.th:9185
```

from this list... I chose 196.235.182.163:24814 for experimenting.

1. When connected to my **mobile wifi** I typed http://196.235.182.163:24814/ in the browser addressbar.
   In return: this page shown below came in response
   [image]
2. when connected to my **institute's wifi** I typed http://196.235.182.163:24814/ in the browser addressbar.
   In return: this **error page** showed up and in another tab that router's logging software's Login page showed up
   **ERROR PAGE**
   [image]

### My question

when connected to institute's wifi, How utorrent is able to connect with that peer at 196.235.182.163:24814 and at the same time my browser shows "Connection timed out" error page when trying to get response from http://196.235.182.163:24814??

How uTorrent is able to connect and not my browser?

### IMPORTANT thing to note

In the browser's address bar when I type in google.com:80 (**port:80**) while connected to institute's router I get a "cant reach page" in browser

AND

when I type in 196.235.182.163:24814 (**port:24814** which falls in the range of 6881 to 65535) while connected to institute's router I get a "connection timed out" in browser

I know a few things about Bittorrent:
standard BitTorrent protocol uses ports 6881 through 6889, however in reality BitTorrent clients may use any port available(maximum possible TCP port number is 65535)

**(maybe these ports are not banned by that router's firewall and can allow communication/torrenting)**

Comment: Read up on [punching holes through NAT and firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)). And you need a publicly accessible server (like the trackers Bittorrent has) to do that.

Comment: by "trackers bittorrent"... are you reffering to the machines that stores the IP addresses of available peers...

**OR**

are you reffering the peers themselves (who provide us the files/download data)?

Comment: [BitTorrent tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker). I guess a peer with a public accessible IP address would also work, but I don't know if this is part of the protocol.